# Why can't my variable be changed for kivy animation?

Tags: python, variables, animation, kivy

I am setting up animations to call another function on_complete and then repeat itself with redefined variables. Except that my variable doesn't change so it applies the repeated animations on the 1st widget spawned. Here is an example:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.button import Button

global Draw_Card
Draw_Card=0
global SpadeCount
SpadeCount=0

##Window.fullscreen = True
##Window.size = (1920, 1080)

Player1Deck=['Spade', 'Spade', 'Spade']

class Spade1(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Spade1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        global CardSetup
        CardSetup=True
        self.b=Button(text='Hello World!')
        self.add_widget(self.b)

        self.bind(pos=self.redraw, size=self.redraw)
        self.size=(186.5 / 2, 259.25 / 2)
        self.pos=(200, 50)

    def Set_Originals(self, x):

        self.Original_pos=x.pos
        self.Original_size=x.size

    def redraw(self, *args):

        self.b.pos=self.pos
        self.b.size=self.size

class Spade2(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Spade2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        global CardSetup
        CardSetup=True
        self.b=Button(text='Hello World!')
        self.add_widget(self.b)

        self.bind(pos=self.redraw, size=self.redraw)
        self.size=(186.5 / 2, 259.25 / 2)
        self.pos=(200, 50)

    def Set_Originals(self, x):

        self.Original_pos=x.pos
        self.Original_size=x.size

    def redraw(self, *args):

        self.b.pos=self.pos
        self.b.size=self.size

class Spade3(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Spade3, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        global CardSetup
        CardSetup=True
        self.b=Button(text='Hello World!')
        self.add_widget(self.b)

        self.bind(pos=self.redraw, size=self.redraw)
        self.size=(186.5 / 2, 259.25 / 2)
        self.pos=(200, 50)

    def Set_Originals(self, x):

        self.Original_pos=x.pos
        self.Original_size=x.size

    def redraw(self, *args):

        self.b.pos=self.pos
        self.b.size=self.size

class DrawCard(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DrawCard, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.anim_queue = []
        self.Draw_Card()

    def Draw_Card(self):
        global Draw_Card
        global CardSetup
        global SpadeCount
        if Draw_Card > 0:

            NextCard=Player1Deck.pop(0)

            if NextCard == 'Spade':
                if SpadeCount==0:
                    self.add_widget(Spade1())
                elif SpadeCount==1:
                    self.add_widget(Spade2())
                elif SpadeCount==2:
                    self.add_widget(Spade3())
                SpadeCount += 1


            PlayerHandCardsList=self.children[:]
            print(PlayerHandCardsList)
            x=len(PlayerHandCardsList)-1
            print(x)
            print(PlayerHandCardsList[x])

            anim = Animation(pos=((493.75) + ((x * 25)), 0),
                             t='in_out_quad', duration=1)
            anim &= Animation(size=(186.5, 259.25),
                              t='in_out_quad', duration=1)

            self.anim_queue.append((PlayerHandCardsList[x], anim))

            w, a = self.anim_queue.pop(0)
            a.bind(on_complete=lambda pos, size: self.WrapUpAnimation(PlayerHandCardsList, x))
            a.start(w)

        else:
            CardSetup=False

    def WrapUpAnimation(self, instance, x):
        global Draw_Card
        instance[x].Set_Originals(instance[x])
        Draw_Card += -1
        self.Draw_Card()

class Game(Widget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        global Draw_Card
        Draw_Card += 3
        self.add_widget(DrawCard())

class GameApp(App):

    def build(self):
        top = Widget()
        top.add_widget(Game())
        return top

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

When the console prints PlayerHandCardsList it correctly shows all widgets added so far. When it prints x, this also is correct. However when PlayerHandCardsList[x] prints, it displays the very first value it was assigned and does not update when the Draw_Card function is repeated. It does however correctly redefine the position x * 25. Why is it doing this!? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out! Because I was redefining the self.children list every time instead of .appending, the newest item was always at index 0! So for this, all you have to do is reference index 0 of the list for each run through!